# how to make a replica of python array class?

Tags: python, iteration, eval, pow

I am trying to customize my own class for iteration, and tries to plug it into the calculations:

```
class Iteration:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

    def __pow__(self, power, modulo=None):
        new_array = list()
        for i in self.array:
            new_array.append(i ** power)
        return new_array

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.array)

    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        return self.array[indices]


def mul(x):
    return x ** 2 + 3 * x ** 3


it = Iteration([1, 2, 3])

print(mul(2))   #=> 28
print(mul(it))  #=> [1, 4, 9, 1, 8, 27, 1, 8, 27, 1, 8, 27]
```

why mul(it) has combined overloaded result? How can I solve this?
I want: 
    print(mul(it))  #=> [4, 28, 90]

Comment: What do think is the value of ``x**2`` when x is ``it``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `__pow__` returns a list, not an `Iteration` instance. The `+` and `*` operations are list operations, and lists implement `+` and `*` as concatenation and repetition.

`[1, 4, 9] + 3 * [1, 8, 27]` repeats `[1, 8, 27]` 3 times to get `[1, 8, 27, 1, 8, 27, 1, 8, 27]`, then concatenates `[1, 4, 9]` and `[1, 8, 27, 1, 8, 27, 1, 8, 27]`.

You need to return an `Iteration` instance from `__pow__`, and you need to implement `__add__` and `__mul__` too, not just `__pow__`. While you're at it, you might also want to implement `__str__` or `__repr__`, so you can see the data your `Iteration` object is wrapping when you print it.